# Safe MD5 digest

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, sha-256, md5

So I've heard that MD5 is broken because it's possible to engineer collisions. So instead we should use, say, SHA256. The problem which SHA256 digests is that they are long. So I've come up with this:

```
function mdsha( input ) { return md5( sha256( input ) ); }
```

So I can retain MD5 digest lengths and avoid malicious collisions.

Is my scheme sound?

Comment: It depends. Do you consider $2^{64}$ SHA-256 evaluations to be infeasible (given that the current complete bitcoin mining network does something in a similar scale every second)? If not this scheme isn't sound.

Comment: Why is it 2^64? MD5 digests are 128 bit...

Comment: @JohnElliotV Collision resistance on the other hand is half the amount of bits because of the birthday problem. That's why hash function outputs are generally double the size of keys for symmetric ciphers. E.g. take a look at [keylength.com / ECRYPT II](https://www.keylength.com/en/3/) recommendations.

Comment: I was thinking that I'll use the last 160 bits (40 hex chars) of a SHA256 digest for my purposes. Would that at least be more secure against malicious collisions than MD5?

Comment: Absolutely. As indicated, it's more standardized to use the first 40 characters though (i.e. the first 160 bits). Note that MD5 hashes are 128 bits, not 160 bits, so you would go outside of MD5 output size. SHA-1 uses 160 bits.

Comment: Note that even though 160-bit hash output size is probably fine for now, **you really don't want to use SHA-1** because chances are it will be broken similarly to MD5 rather sooner than later.

Comment: Are 160 bits taken from SHA256 stronger than 160 bit SHA1..?

Comment: Yes, because of (see original question).

Comment: Could you please explain why is it a problem with the size ?

Comment: I don't want long URLs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your scheme is likely sound as the SHA-256 hash limits the input to the MD5 hashing function. If this was not so it could be possible (though very hard) to create a collision because of the break.

Generally it is more secure to simply use the 128 leftmost bits of the output of SHA-256. SHA-3 - or rather SHAKE256 - would be even better if available.

Keep in mind that 128 bits is relatively small with regards to collision resistance due to the birthday problem. The birthday problem will reduce the collision resistance to half the output size. It may not directly be an issue, but you may want to consider upgrading your protocol to use a larger hash value.

Comment: The last paragraph is important. 128-bit hash means ~$2^{64}$ collision attack, which is expensive, but plausible. One option to increase collision resistance would be an iterated hash.

Comment: I tried searching for "iterated hash" but still don't understand what that means. How do I do an iterated hash..?

Comment: @JohnElliotV H(H(H...H(M)...)) where the number of hashes is large, e.g. 10K or 100K. The idea is that an attacker also needs to perform all those hashes, but $2^{64}$ times to perform the attack. Needless to say, this will cost you CPU cycles.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I have rather humble security requirements (I'm not trying to beat the NSA!) and I'd rather avoid paying the computational tax I would have to pay to do the iterated hashing so I think I'll just take 168 bits from SHA256 and be done. (Because: 42!)

Comment: @JohnElliotV if you want computation to be faster, and you have a 64-bit system, SHA-512 will be faster with 64-bit code

Comment: I added [profanity filtering](https://www.progclub.org/pcrepo/jj5-test/trunk/jjcode/jjcode.php?revision=2881#l58) which kind of serves in the same way as an iterated hash... I can only generate 100 hashes per second (in PHP), which I feel is pretty slow.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes SHAKE256 is available, isn't it ? As specified by FIPS 202.

Comment: @Biv As standard for sure, but I don't know if the runtime of John also contains it.

Comment: @JohnElliotV That's a good measure, but if the attacker can execute hash functions then it won't matter much. So you'd have to integrate a secret value. In that case you may need a HMAC, PBKDF or KBKDF instead of "just" a hash. It depends on the protocol if such a countermeasure would be OK (and I cannot quickly see that from the code).

Comment: I use an (optional) salt. See [here](https://www.progclub.org/pcrepo/jj5-test/trunk/jjcode/jjcode.php?revision=2888#l69). The hashes are iterated if any blacklisted strings appear and the only way to know that is to scan the hash for the substring over one thousand times per hash...

Comment: Secret salts are sometimes called pepper. If they remain secure the protocol could well work. But we're already using up too much comment space, a full protocol analysis is too much.